# How do I convert an avatar URL to .png?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, jimp

How do I convert the avatar URL to .png?

```
Error: Unsupported MIME type: image/webp
    at Jimp.throwError (/rbd/pnpm-volume/d0d23ade-48c6-41ba-b84e-4a28aa8daecb/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/@jimp/utils/0.14.0/node_modules/@jimp/utils/dist/index.js:33:13)
```

Comment: Can you share the code you tried ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `displayAvatarURL()` or `avatarURL()`, you can set the `format` to `png`. That way, you'll get a PNG image instead of webp. As an example:

```js
user.displayAvatarURL();
// would become
user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png' });
```

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that image type webp is not supported

You can know more about webp [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp)

Try using [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webp-converter#convert-webp-image-to-other-image-format) to convert webp.

Run the following commands